# NullPointerException after adding XPM to dd4t web site

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, dd4t

I am trying to added the Experience Manager Web site extension to the our dd4t 2.0 website. I got this error when I request a page.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:136)
>           at com.tridion.util.URIUtils.urlDecode(URIUtils.java:137)
>           at com.tridion.preview.web.util.SessionRequestDetails.(SessionRequestDetails.java:52)
>           at com.tridion.preview.web.AbstractContentFilter.doFilter(AbstractContentFilter.java:50)
>           at com.tridion.preview.web.PageContentFilter.doFilter(PageContentFilter.java:9)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
>           at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>           at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Looking at the error I see Session, our website doesn't use session. Do I need session to make XPM work?

**Update after comment:**

The application is JAVA based and was working before adding XPM. I provided "Content Delivery Endpoint URL" and "Website URL" values in the session preview tab of the Publish Target and published the page. I have also added the XPM markup tags to the page views, but I still get the above error in my WebLogic server log.

I have verified that the url I provided to "Content Delivery Endpoint URL" works. I followed the instructions provided [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2565011A-E64E-4713-81E3-3AE7835607BB) to setup the XPM web service (skipped the Ambient Data Framework setup) and [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3F764ABD-462F-43A8-BB3F-83928CE48215) for adding XPM to my application (skipped the Ambient Data Framework setup).

Comment: Hi Anindita,

Just the error detail can not show the clear picture like what have you done so far.
Kindly provide some more details about the steps you have followed to implement XPM on DD4T application.
Have you added the details in session preview tab in Publication target?
Also, was the page working earlier without XPM setting implemented?
Is your application Java based or Dotnet based?
Provide some more details so that community users can help you better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue by going through the post "[Troubleshooting the SDL Tridion Experience Manager with Session Preview](http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/)".

I had `PageContentFilter` defined in by web.xml. A DD4T application doesn't need this filter. Removing the filter from my web.xml fixed the above error.